# connect.sid not generated in Bluemix

Tags: javascript, node.js

We have some JavaScript lines working fine on local node.js (and Mongo.db).
But when we moved the code to BlueMix, something does not work.
Let me explain.

I see in the chrome browser there is a cookie named "connect.sid" when all is ok (local server).

And "connect.sid" is not present when code runs in Bluemix, so I can not use "request.session".

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

One probable reason could be that due to  httpOnly flag is being set. pls. do check on this.

Comment: mr Kumar : whet I generate the cookies, I can do whatever I want. Here is my code

Comment: res.cookie( 'kukH0',        ++iCnt, { httpOnly: false } ) ;
res.cookie( 'kukH1',        ++iCnt, { httpOnly: true } ) ;
res.cookie( 'kukSIG1',      ++iCnt, { signed: true } ) ;
res.cookie( 'kukSIG1H1',    ++iCnt, { signed: true, httpOnly: true  } ) ;
res.cookie( 'kukSIG1SEC1',  ++iCnt, { signed: true, secure: true } ) ;
res.cookie( 'kukTIT',       'MYTIT', { httpOnly: false, signed: false } ) ;
res.cookie( 'kukVER',        myVersio, { httpOnly: false, signed: false } ) ;
res.cookie( 'kukCON.SID',   'MYSID', { signed: true, httpOnly: true, secure: false } ) ;

Comment: but the CONNECT.SID cookie is NOT generated by users, but ... I dont know ... by node.js (?) ... by HTTPS handler (?)